# Writing constraint in CPLEX OPL

Tags: optimization, cplex, opl

I have a problem in writing constraint. 
I have one mobile phone number, 4 tariff package and 9 months. For now, solution is giving different tariff for each month.
I would like to write constraint so that solution gives same tariff for each model

```
    //DATA
 {string} numbers = ...;//mobile phone number, id, FOR NOW ONLY ONE NUMBER
 {string} usageCategories = ...;//{"fixed""mobile""international""data"}

 tuple packageInfo { 
    string name;
    float price;
    float fixedMinutes;
    float mobileMinutes;
    float internationalMinutes;
    float data; 
 };

 {packageInfo} packages = ...;//tariff package info

 float UsageFixed[numbers] = ...;//fixed min used
 float UsageMobile[numbers] = ...;//mobile other min used
 float UsageInternational[numbers] = ...;//international numbers used
 float UsageData[numbers] = ...; //data traffic (kb)
 float taxfree[numbers] = ...; //tax free items
 float InternationalServices[numbers] = ...; //international services
 float pricePerMinute[usageCategories] = ...;//price per minute after minutes included in package

 //minutes included in package for each number...calculated in execute block overageFactor
 float overageFixed[numbers][packages];
 float overageMobile[numbers][packages];
 float overageInternational[numbers][packages];
 float overageData[numbers][packages];



 //DECISION VARS
 dvar boolean assign[numbers][packages];


 //overage amount
 execute overageFactor {

    for (var n in numbers) {
        for (var p in packages) {
            if (UsageFixed[n] < p.fixedMinutes)
                overageFixed[n][p] = 0;
            else overageFixed[n][p] = UsageFixed[n] - p.fixedMinutes;

            if (UsageMobile[n] < p.mobileMinutes)
                overageMobile[n][p] = 0;
            else overageMobile[n][p] = UsageMobile[n] - p.mobileMinutes;

            if (UsageInternational[n] < p.internationalMinutes)
                overageInternational[n][p] = 0;
            else overageInternational[n][p] = UsageInternational[n] - p.internationalMinutes; 

            if (UsageData[n] < p.data)
                overageData[n][p] = 0;
            else overageData[n][p] = UsageData[n] - p.data;     
        }   
    }

};

 dexpr float packagesCost = sum (n in numbers, p in packages) p.price * assign[n][p]; //package cost

 //overage costs
 dexpr float fixedOverageCost[p in packages, n in numbers] = 
                                    overageFixed[n][p] * assign[n][p] * pricePerMinute["fixed"];
 dexpr float mobileOverageCost[p in packages, n in numbers] =
                                    overageMobile[n][p] * assign[n][p] * pricePerMinute["mobile"];
 dexpr float internationalOverageCost[p in packages, n in numbers] = 
                                    overageInternational[n][p] * assign[n][p] * pricePerMinute["international"];
 dexpr float dataOverageCost[p in packages, n in numbers] = 
                                    overageData[n][p] * assign[n][p] * pricePerMinute["data"];

 dexpr float cost = packagesCost + sum (p in packages, n in numbers)
                            (fixedOverageCost[p,n] + mobileOverageCost[p,n] + internationalOverageCost[p,n] + dataOverageCost[p,n])
                       + sum (n in numbers) taxfree[n]
                       + sum (n in numbers) InternationalServices[n];

 //OBJECTIVE
 minimize cost;



 //CONSTRAINTS
 subject to {

    //one package for each number
    forall (n in numbers)
        sum (p in packages) assign[n,p] == 1;

    //every month same package

    ?????????????????????????

 };


 //Data display
 tuple assignedPackage {
    string id;
    string package; 
 };

 {assignedPackage} assignedPackages = {<i,p.name> | i in numbers, p in packages : assign[i,p] == 1};

 execute dataDisplay {
    writeln ("Assign following packages to users:");
    for (var i in assignedPackages)
        writeln (i); 
 }

 current solution:

 <"7" "VPN ZA SVE S">
 <"6" "VPN ZA SVE L">
 <"8" "VPN ZA SVE S">
 <"9" "VPN ZA SVE S">
 <"10" "VPN ZA SVE L">
 <"11" "VPN ZA SVE M">
 <"12" "VPN ZA SVE M">
 <"1" "VPN ZA SVE S">
 <"2" "VPN ZA SVE M">
```

Comment: It seems to be a bit confused - you refer to both months and numbers as the same thing? Also, if you want to enforce just one package for each number over all the months, then why do you have different variables for each month for the same number? Why not have a single variable for which package gets assigned? If you really need to have a separate variable for each month, then just add constraints that set them all the same. So use e.g. assign[month2] == assign[month1] and assign[month3] == assign[month1] etc

Comment: instead of number I put months in {string} numbers = ...; because each month is same number and in sets duplicates aren't allowed.
so {string} numbers = ...; contains 6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3 (numbers representing months). I already tried to write assign == assign and so on but cplex is giving me error

Comment: I still don't understand why you have a variable for each month, when you want to have the same value for that variable for all months. Why not just one variable across all months? If you need this, then something like forall (p in packages) forall (n in numbers) assign[n,p] == assign[previous(n),p];  but you will have to look up how to get the previous number, and take care of the edge cases at the start/end of the loop.